# Resources for developing .NET applications for Windows Vista/7?

Tags: .net, windows-7, windows-vista, uac

I am looking for some resources for developing .NET apps for Windows Vista/7. 
What are the challenges? Are there resources on dealing with UAC? What about upgrading a large enterprise XP application?

We have a large WinForms application written in C# with the .NET 2.0 framework. We are tasked with getting this application to run on Windows7. Upgrading to WPF, .NET 3.5, .NET 4.0 etc. is not an option. Any help pointing to blogs, books etc. would be great.

Comment: Have you tried running it on Windows Vista/7?

Comment: Really not sure why that comment got +1...yes, we've run it on Vista/Win7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might benefit from a talk I have given a lot of places about using the [Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack/) to add jumplists, taskbar overlays, etc to your application. [Here is a recording of it](http://www.msteched.com/2009/Europe/DEV309) from Tech Ed Europe last year. I also have a [blog category](http://www.gregcons.com/KateBlog/CategoryView.aspx?category=Windows%207) for Windows 7 development - I hope you would find it helpful.

Step 1 - try running it. See what works and doesn't work. Understand your UAC issues and change the code to stop assuming your users are admin. Step 2 - add some simple light-ups like those in my talk above. Step 3 - consider using other Windows 7 features that might require bigger changes, but only after you've got it working (step 1) and looking like a Windows 7 app (step 2.)